# Is there a way to delete a view on scraperwiki?

Tags: scraperwiki

Is there a way to delete a view on scraperwiki?  I can't find a way to do that anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, click the "Admin" button at the top of the View's overview page, and choose "Delete View".